# Sort strings by last letter (Alphabetically) in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, sorting

Given an array of strings

```
var lastLetterSort = [ 'blue', 'red', 'green' ];
```

How would you sort the strings in alphabetical order using using their last letter, ideally with a sort function / compare function?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort

Answer (score 4):

It's easier to just use the `charCodeAt` property, which returns a number associated with a character. Letters that occur later in the alphabet tend to have a higher value

```
function last(x){
    return x.sort((a, b) => a.charCodeAt(a.length - 1) - b.charCodeAt(b.length - 1));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try like this

```js
var lastLetterSort = ['blue', 'red', 'green', 'aa'];


var sorted = lastLetterSort.sort(function(a, b) {

    if (a[a.length - 1] > b[b.length - 1])
        return 1;
    else if (a[a.length - 1] < b[b.length - 1])
        return -1;

    return 0;

})

console.log(sorted)
```

Comment: A callback must return a number, not boolean. It's just an accident that for given data it worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

```
lastLetterSort.sort(function(a, b){
    var lastA = a.charAt(a.length - 1);
    var lastB = b.charAt(b.length - 1);
    if (lastA > lastB) {
        return 1;
    } else if (lastA < lastB) {
        return -1;
    } else {
        return 0;
    }
});
```

Comment: Now `var`s for variables are lost

Answer (score 0):

Since "a" < "b", you can make a compare function and pass it to [Array.sort()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort).

```
var colors = ["blue", "red", "green"];

function endComparator(a,b) {
    if (a.slice(-1) < b.slice(-1)) return -1;
    if (a.slice(-1) > b.slice(-1)) return 1;
    return 0;
}

colors.sort(endComparator); // ["red", "blue", "green"]
```

Using [slice()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/slice) means the comparator can be used on Arrays, too:

```
var nums = [[0,1,2], [0,1,1]];
nums.sort(endComparator); // [[0,1,1], [0,1,2]]
```